# Clamping Diodes - Any disadvantages form continuously clamp down?

Tags: diodes, level-shifting, esd

I am looking at using Clamping diodes to protect my Raspberry Pi UART pins from over voltage. [The ESD Diodes I am looking at using](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/698115.pdf)

My question is, is there any harm in them continuously clamping down the voltage?

Looking at the datasheet I could also tell if they had a life span before they stop clamping down

Comment: There is no information in the datasheet regarding continuous operation. This is not entirely a surprise as they are usually not intended for continuous operation.

Comment: One potential problem with operating the clamping diodes continuously is electromigration, which could lead to open circuits in your ESD ring and leave your UART unprotected.  As Ignacio said, the diodes are not intended for continuous operation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that raises the question of when do they kick in. I know they say 3.3V is the clamping voltage but do they then stay on if the RPI 3.3V voltage is say 3.35V?

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the datasheet you linked, on page 5, \$V_{BR}\$ (breakdown voltage) is the "clamp-down voltage" where the diode starts to conduct. For the 3.3V diode, it is at 6.4V typ. One obvious conclusion is, ESD diodes are quite imprecise and may not be good for tight overvoltage protection. So your worry is not whether it will be continuously clamping down the voltage, but rather will it clamp down at a voltage level where you consider as overvoltage.

Following is one example (which may or may not be what you want) of how to use the ESD diode :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxvL60.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

New edit in response to comment:

Look in the datasheet you linked, on Page 8 Fig 8, at \$V_{RWM}\$ (e.g. 3.3V), only \$I_{RM}\$ leakage current of around 1uA flows through the diode. Therefore for a signal up to 3.3V, very very little loading comes from the ESD diode and the signal is essentially unaffected.

At \$V_{BR}\$ break down voltage (e.g. 6.4V), the current through the diode takes a sharp turn upward. And it is this sharp up turn in current sinking capability that would try to clamp the voltage near the break down voltage.

With the voltage clamped at around 6.4V-8V, that is high enough to damage typical 3.3V logic, so a resistor can be added to limit the current into the 3.3V logic pin. But when adding such a series resistor, loading and conditions of the signal must be considered and it may not be functionally acceptable.

Also, for typical digital logic, an unidirectional diode gives better protection because it provides added protection for negative going glitches.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused. Is the breakdown voltage(6.4V) when it will not allow any flow at all and reverse standoff voltage(3.3V) where no significant conduction occurs?